# Checking my understanding of derivative notation

Tags: calculus

Say I have an equation $x^2+x-2$.

If I wanted to say that I needed to take the derivative, I would write ${d\over dx}x^2+x-2$ or ${\Delta y \over \Delta x}={((x+\Delta x)^2+(x +\Delta x)-2)-(x^2+x-2) \over \Delta x}$.

If I have already taken the derivate, I would write ${dy \over dx}=2x+1$.

Is anything wrong with what I have written or are there better or more clear ways?

Comment: If you have $y=x^2+x-2$, then the last line should be $\frac{dx}{dy}\color{red}{=}2x+1$

Comment: ah, I see, so if I left off the = sign, does that then mean to take the derivative just like $d \over dy$?

Comment: @user1489829 With that notation, you place the variable that you are differentiating with respect to in the denominator. $\frac{d}{dy}$ would mean that you're differentiating with respect to $y$, but you aren't, so it should be $\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: Ah, I realized that I had made that mistake and edited my post, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean $y = x^2+x-2$?

In that case: $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ is an operator, and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is a function.

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2+x-2)=2x+1$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for the quick answer. What does it mean mathematically if I leave off the y=? Or rather, if I leave off the y=, what should I think?

Comment: @user1489829 Things like $dy/dx$ would be meaningless without the $y=$ as $y$ has not been defined.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @user1489829 You are very welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, the derivative is defined as the limit:

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

Substitute: $y = x^2 + x + 1, y+\Delta y = (x+\Delta x)^2 + (x+\Delta x) - 2$
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{((x+\Delta x)^2 + (x+\Delta x) - 2) - (x^2 + x -2)}{\Delta x}$$

Expand:
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{(x^2+2x\Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 + x+\Delta x - 2) - (x^2 + x -2)}{\Delta x}$$

Perform the subtraction:
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{2x\Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 + \Delta x}{\Delta x}$$

Perform the division:
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (2x + \Delta x + 1)$$

Take the limit:
$$\therefore \frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} = 2x + 1$$

Comment: $\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$??

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ right?